# How can I configure VSCode rust-analyzer Rust plugin to accept arguments for the shortcuts in the Editor body

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I am getting started using VSCode withe the rust-analyzer plugin. I really like the ">Run" "shortcuts" that the plugin adds to all the functions and tests.

How can I pass in command line arguments to these shortcuts ?

I tried to edit the launch.json file and added in the command line arguments there. But these get passed in only when I call --Main Menu--Run--Run without debugging.

Is there a way to configure the "Run" "shortcut" to accept arguments?

I am attaching a snapshot of the "shortcut" button ( around line 22) in case I am not describing it accurately.
[image: Screenshot of VSCode window with "Run" Shortcut around line 22]

The launch.json below allowed me to pass command line arguments to "Run" that gets called from the Main Menu--using Run--Run without debugging . However that is slower and runs in a separate console. Is there an easy way to pass arguments to the shortcut?

```json
    {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "lldb",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Debug executable 'gcd_euclid_cli'",
                "cargo": {
                    "args": [
                        "build",
                        "--bin=gcd_euclid_cli",
                        "--package=gcd_euclid_cli"
                    ],
                    "filter": {
                        "name": "gcd_euclid_cli",
                        "kind": "bin"
                    }
                },
                "args": ["1024", "578"],
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            {
                "type": "lldb",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "Debug unit tests in executable 'gcd_euclid_cli'",
                "cargo": {
                    "args": [
                        "test",
                        "--no-run",
                        "--bin=gcd_euclid_cli",
                        "--package=gcd_euclid_cli"
                    ],
                    "filter": {
                        "name": "gcd_euclid_cli",
                        "kind": "bin"
                    }
                },
                "args": ["1024", "578"],
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        ]
    }
```